# Licence billing

Tags: commerce

My question is regarding the recurring payment for drupal commerce.

I use [Commerce Licence](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license) with 'Licence role' and [Commerce Licence Billing](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license_billing) to make my users pay for a monthly subscription.

The question I have is, how does the recurring system work?

- Does the licence Role expire after given time, but gets re-acitvated if a payment is made?
- Does the recurring payment happen automatically, or does my user have to buy a licence every month?
- Does the previous question depend on my "Payment Gateway"?

What I want to do is make my users buy a licence(Role) once, and then never have to buy a licence again.  But they have to pay a monthly fee otherwise the licence will expire.  So in other words the site much purchase a licence for the user in the background when the previous one expires, but charge them the monthly fee.

It's a tedious process to go and buy a licence(role) every month to keep using the site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this module today and i am having same questions :) I have understand quite things.

A partof the answer in the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2127603) of the module :

After a license is renewed, the queue "commerce_license_billing_cycle_close" will set the "Recurring: Payment pending" status to the order.

```
$order->status = 'recurring_payment_pending';
commerce_order_save($order);
```

If you use [commerce card on file](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cardonfile) module, a default rules will try to charge the user credit card and then the Order will have a "Completed" status.

Otherwise, user will have to pay line items through the site to have the order completed.

To answer your first question, if i understand, the module will renew license without manage the payment but will create corresponding orders with a specific status. Either you charge your client with a specific rule or tell your client to pay different orders.

For the second question, your customer will get the license every months automatically and will have to pay (if you don't do it via a rule) after.